# Annotation equivalent to Component in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am aware that using the  component tag I can use a part of the class and make it available in an entity in hibernate.

How do i achieve this through annotations. Or otherwise, what is the annotation equivalent to  tag.

@Embedded isn't exact solution as in my case i need only few fields from the one which i intend to use as component.

Kindly throw some light.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `@Embeddable` along with `@Column` and `@Transient`?

Also, it might be better to extract the 'component' into its own class and use it in the entity as well as the original class (where the fields were defined before extraction).